# Writing large file in Nodejs using fs.createWriteStream

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have function, which in perfect world should create an huge 1M lines file. Here it is:

```
    const fileWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.resolve(filePath));
    let ableToWrite = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
        if (ableToWrite) {
            ableToWrite = fileWriteStream.write(`.testClass${itr}-${i%2} { background: red } \n`);
        } else {
            fileWriteStream.once('drain', () => {
                ableToWrite = fileWriteStream.write(`.testClass${itr}-${i%2} { background: red } \n`);
            })
        }
    }
```

Unfortunetly for me, i'm getting the following error pretty fast:

```
MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

I don't really want to increase listeners count for this function.
What is correct way to write such a big file using streams?

Many thanks!

Comment: You're going to need another means of flow control: a recursive function, generator, etc.

Comment: Do you understand *why* your current code adds 99999 listeners?

Comment: @Bergi To be honest not really. I know that i  have limit for subscribtions, but it looks like this code only add new watchers and watchers which has already been added not work at all

Comment: @YafimDziuko The problem is that it doesn't wait after adding the listeners. So in the following iterations (`ableToWrite` still being false) it continues to add all the listeners - everything before even the first event fires. And when it fires, it fires all the listeners waiting for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to asynchronously continue when the stream drains is to use `await` in the loop with a promise:

```
const fileWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.resolve(filePath));
for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
    const ableToWrite = fileWriteStream.write(`.testClass${itr}-${i%2} { background: red } \n`);
    if (!ableToWrite) {
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            fileWriteStream.once('drain', resolve);
        });
    }
}
```

The alternative is using a recursive approach instead of a loop:

```
function go(i) {
    if (i >= 1e6) return;
    const ableToWrite = fileWriteStream.write(`.testClass${itr}-${i%2} { background: red } \n`);
    if (ableToWrite)
        go(i+1);
    else
        fileWriteStream.once('drain', () => {
            go(i+1);
        });
}
const fileWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.resolve(filePath));
go(0);
```

Comment: would `await new Promise(fileWriteStream.once.bind(fileWriteStream, 'drain'))` work? Not sure if that's a good idea since that might implicitly do something with `reject`, but I've never tested that.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I guess it would work as [`once`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_once_eventname_listener) ignores a third argument, but I still don't think it's a good idea because the arrow function is simply much more readable.

Comment: @Bergi First solution works really fine, thx! But can you please explain one thing - until new Promise wont be resolved, for loop will be paused? Looks like it shoud, because line order in file seems correct

Comment: @Bergi Tested it, await new Promise really pausing for loop untill it won't be resolved. Wow!
Big thanks for your help